# Oracle SQL - Joins with condition

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm sorry for asking these questions but I am really new and studying Oracle SQL for my university and I am having a hard time with a few things. Anyways, for this one, I am supposed to retrieve data from 2 different tables. One is from 'STAFF' and one is from 'BRANCH' I want the output to display the staff name (SNAME), the start date (STARTDATE) and the area (AREA). SNAME and STARTDATE are from the table 'STAFF', and the AREA is from the table 'Branch', how do I access that? Also, I ONLY want to display the names and start dates of those who are in the STOKE areea.

This is my code

```
SELECT SNAME, STARTDATE, BRANCH.AREA
    FROM STAFF CROSS JOIN BRANCH
        WHERE STAFF.BRANCHID = 20;
```

Note: The STAFF.BRANCHID = 20 is because the area 'STOKE' has a BRANCHID of 20.

This is what I get:

```
SNAME      STARTDATE AREA         
---------- --------- -------------
SMITH      15-NOV-00 ECCLESHALL   
JONES      02-MAR-01 ECCLESHALL   
SONG       03-JAN-02 ECCLESHALL   
SMITH      15-NOV-00 STOKE              
SONG       03-JAN-02 STOKE        
SMITH      15-NOV-00 STAFFORD
```

As you can see, the WHERE clause is not working because it outputs every area instead of stoke only.

I know I am supposed to use the JOIN function but I don't get which one and why, any useful links would be appreciated :)

Thank you

Comment: didn't get, why you use `WHERE STAFF.BRANCHID = 20;` instead of `WHERE BRANCH.AREA = 'STOKE';`. Also you need to specify a join condition which is `ON STAFF.BRANCHID = BRANCH.ID` I guess (you didn't specify the table schemas so I'm just guessing that there is `ID` column in table `BRANCH`)

Comment: Ahhh that's why it was doing that. Thank you!

Comment: How are these two tables related? Is their any branch indicator in staff table?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `INNER JOIN` and proper join condition as follows:

```
SELECT S.SNAME, S.STARTDATE, B.AREA
  FROM STAFF S INNER JOIN BRANCH B
    ON S.BRANCHID = B.BRANCHID
 WHERE S.AREA = 'STOKE';
```